# React-Native setState not updating state asynchronously

Tags: react-native, setstate

```
import React from 'react';
import {View}  from 'react-native';
import Button from 'react-native-button';

const gData  = [{counter: 0}];

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {data: {}};
    console.log("Constructor: ", this.state.data);
  }
  _handlePress()
  {
    console.log("Pressed Button")
    gData[0].counter += 1;
    console.log("Before setState: ", gData);
    this.setState({data: gData}, console.log("After setState: ", this.state.data));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent: 'center',}}>
        <Button
          onPress={() => this._handlePress()}>
          Press Me!
        </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hi, 
I have this simple code for an react-native application which creates a button on the screen that upon press it should update a counter within an object and store the object in the state. However when I run the app and press the button I get this in my logs:

11:19:43 PM: Running app on Android SDK built for x86_64

11:19:43 PM: Constructor:  {}

11:23:20 PM: Pressed Button

11:23:20 PM: Before setState:  [{"counter":1}]

11:23:20 PM: After setState:  {}

So for some reason the state is not updated. Does anyone know what that is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure if you call console.log like that it will be invoked immediately instead of once the state is done updating, try putting it into an anonymous function:

```
    this.setState({data: gData}, () => console.log("After setState: ", this.state.data));
```

Comment: You are right! Thanks! They always say the second argument is a callback once the update is complete so it is easy to miss that you need an anonymous function to wrap it. At least if you are a novice like myself...